# Time-lapse photography with 360° in 30 minutes

Tags: timelapse, gopro

I like traveling and I'm interested in making time-lapse video with GoPro camera.

Most of the panning mounts make 360° in 60 minutes. Often I don't have that much time, specially when hiking and cutting that time in half would be good for me.

I cannot find exact examples of this, so I'm wondering if this will make final video not so smooth?

Comment: Taking multiple still images for the purpose of creating a time-lapse video is specifically on topic here. Please see http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4715/are-time-lapse-questions-off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this if you want. The first question is how long a video do you want to produce? To make it look smooth, best to have about 25 or 30 frames per second.

So if you want a 1 minute video, you would need 1800 photos. Which means taking 60 photos per minute for 30 minutes, or 1 photo per second. So you can set your GoPro to record this.

Also depends on what you are recording in the timelapse. ie what is actually changing or moving. Some of the most impressive landscape timelapses feature changes in the weather, or clouds moving across the sky. In many places the weather can change dramatically in 30 minutes. But in other places the weather is more static, so a longer timelapse would be more interesting.

Comment: Great answer. Do you know if gopro gives you an option for which file format you would like to save the photos? I say this because this may add or decrease the number of photos one could take in a minute video, because of lossless vs lossy